# Why is $f$ or $-f$ convex in this case?

Tags: analysis, functions, convex-analysis

In some notes I found this statement:

Let $f$ be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$ there is a line that goes through $(x, f(x))$ and the graph of $f$ is only at the one side of the line. Then either $f$ or $-f$ is convex.

Why does this hold? It is not clear for me why the function has to be convex then.

Could you explain that to me?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

Let $a<b$.

If $(b, f(b))$ is above the line that passes through $(a, f(a))$ and $(a, f(a))$ is above the line that passes through $(b, f(b))$, then the slope of the line through $(b, f(b))$ must be larger than the slope of the line through $(a, f(a))$.

The line through $(a, f(a))$ is the graph of $g(x)=m_1(x-a)+f(a)$ and since $(b, f(b))$ is above that line, we have $f(b)>m_1(b-a)+f(a)$.

Similarily, the line through $(b, f(b))$ is the graph of $h(x)=m_2(x-b)+f(b)$ and since $(a, f(a))$ is above that line, we have $f(a)>m_2(a-b)+f(b)$.

Is everything correct so far? How could we continue?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a line $l_i$ through $(x_i,f(x_i)),\ x_0<x_1$ s.t. the line $l_i$ is given by $y_i
 (x)=m_i(x-x_i) +f(x_i)$ and the graph of $f$ is in oneside wrt each line $l_i$

If $f$ is linear, then we are done. Now we assume that $f$ is not a linear.

> **Step 1 :** $f(x)\leq y_i(x)$ for all $i$ and all $x$ (concave case)

or $f(x)\geq y_i(x)$ for all $i$ and all $x$ (convex case)

Proof : We will prove by a contradiction. Assume that $f
 (x)\leq y_0(x)$ for all $x$ and $f(x)\geq y_1(x)$ for all $x$.

If two lines are not **parallel**, then they intersects. When we consider the graph around intersection point, we have a contradiction.

Hence two lines are parallel. In the long run, such lines at any point $(x,f(x))$ are parallel. Hence we completes the proof.

**Step 2 :** Now we assume that for any $a$, there is $m_a$ s.t. $f(x)\leq m_a(x-a) +f(a) $ for all $x$.

Now we will prove that $f$ is concave i.e. $f(t-s) + f(t+s) \leq 2 f(t)\ \ast$ for $s>0$.

At $t$, there is $m_t$ so that $$f(t-s)\leq m_t(t-s -t) +f(t) $$

$$ f(t+s)\leq m_t(t+s-t) +f(t) $$

which implies $\ast$.

Comment: If $f$ is concave then $-f$ is convex, right? So to get a proof by contradiction we assume that $f(x)\leq y_i(x)$ is not true? Why can we assume that $f$ is not a line? And why at the last case we conclude that $f$ must be a line?

Comment: When $f$ is a line, then we are done. And if $f$ is between any two parallel lines among three lines, then $f$ must be a line.

Comment: Why are we done when $f$ is a line? I got stuck right now.

Comment: You mean we get a contradiction then?

Comment: When $f$ is a line, then $f$ is concave.

Comment: Could we do also the following?

Comment: Let $a<b$. If $(b, f(b))$ is above the line that passes through $(a, f(a))$ and $(a, f(a))$ is above the line that passes through $(b, f(b))$, then the slope of the line through $(b, f(b))$ must be larger than the slope of the line through $(a, f(a))$. The line through $(a, f(a))$ is the graph of $g(x)=m_1(x-a)+f(a)$ and since $(b, f(b))$ is above that line, we have $f(b)>m_1(b-a)+f(a)$. Similarily, the line through $(b, f(b))$ is the graph of $h(x)=m_2(x-b)+f(b)$ and since $(a, f(a))$ is above that line, we have $f(a)>m_2(a-b)+f(b)$.

Comment: Is everything correct so far? How do we get from here the desired result?

Comment: Or is this a wrong attempt?

Comment: "When we consider the graph around intersection point, we have a contradiction." How do we ge a contradiction? I got stuck right now. So we suppose that there is a $x^{\star}$ such that $y_0(x^{\star})=y_1(x^{\star})$, right? Is the graph in that case not at one side of the line? Or which is the contradiction? And after that... "In the long run, such lines at any point (x,f(x)) are parallel. Hence we completes the proof." Because all the lines $y_i(x)$ are parallel, then $f(x)$ must either be smaller than all lines or larger than all lines?

Comment: When we have an intersection point $(x^\ast,f(x^\ast))$, draw the picture. Then it is almost automatically clear.

Comment: For the second question, if $x_0<x_2<x_1$, then the graph of $f$ is between two parallel lines $l_0,\ l_1\neq l_0$. Then we have a line $l_2$ intersecting $l_0,\ l_1$ for some $x_2$. This contradicts to thing that all such lines are parallel.

Comment: Why do we have a line $\ell_2$ that intersects $\ell_0$ and $\ell_1$ ?

Comment: Note that $(x_2,f(x_2))$ is a point between $l_0,\ l_1$ so that if $l_2$ is parallel to them, then the graph of $f$ is between $l_0,\ l_2$ (or between $l_1,\ l_2$), which implies $f$ does not meet $l_1$.

Comment: So the fact that $f$ does not meet $\ell_1$ is a contradiction because $\ell_1$ is the lilne through $(x_1, f(x_1))$, right?

Comment: Yes. it is right.

Comment: And with this contradiction we get that $f$ must be linear, right?

Comment: Ah no we get that the proposition of step 1 is valid, right?